# How to read the value of a string stored in a text file, then convert to integer, and do math on value?

Tags: python, concatenation

I've been writing Python code for only about 4 weeks. I'm writing a little text based game to learn and test everything I know. I can easily make this work with a value entered into the console as an integer, but for whatever reason I can't get my code to work with reading this value from a text file.

Earlier in the program, my code saves a value to a text file, just one value, then later it opens the same text file, over-writes the value with a new value based on a very simple calculation. That calculation is the first value, plus 5. I've spent a bunch of time reading on this site and going through my books and at this point I'm pretty sure I'm just missing something obvious.

The first piece of code that creates the doc and sets the value:

```
def set_hp(self):
    f = open('player_hp.txt', 'w')
    self.hitpoints = str(int(self.hitpoints))
    f.write(self.hitpoints)
    f.close()
```

This is the trouble section...I have commented the line with the problem.

```
def camp_fire():
    print
    print "You stop to build a fire and rest..."
    print "Resting will restore your health."
    print "You gather wood from the ground around you. You spark\n\
your flint against some tinder. A flame appears.\n\
You sit, and close your eyes in weariness. A peaceful calm takes you\n\
into sleep."
    f = open('player_hp.txt', 'r')
    orig_hp = f.readlines()
    orig_hp = str(orig_hp)
    f = open('player_hp.txt', 'w')
    new_value = orig_hp + 5    ##this is where my code breaks
    new_value = str(int(new_value))
    f.write(new_value)
    f.close()
    print "You have gained 5 hitpoints from resting. Your new HP are {}.".format(new_value)
```

This is the error I get:

```
  File "C:\Python27\Awaken03.py", line 300, in camp_fire
    new_value = orig_hp + 5
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects
```

I know you can't concatenate a string and an integer, but I keep trying different methods to convert the string to an integer to do the quick math, but I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: @Carcigenicate see the next line, OP is trying to convert string to int and then back to string, so perhaps its not what OP is after i think.

Comment: This is a good first post. My small recommendation, for even better questions, is to use technical writing - we like succinctness here. There's no need for niceties or chit-chat - just describe your general problem, what you have done to try to solve it, and any notes on where you think the problem is. This looks pretty good now.

Comment: Thank you SMA and halfer! I was able to fix my code. It works great now. Much appreciated Dan :)

Answer (score 0):

Error message is clear, you are trying to concatenate string with an integer. You should change the line from:

```
new_value = orig_hp + 5
```

To:

```
new_value = str(int(orig_hp) + 5)
```

Then you can use above value to write directly into file as a string as:

```
##new_value = str(int(new_value))## Skip this line
f.write(new_value)
```

Comment: I'm adding this to my notes for future reference! And my code is working. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

[f.readlines()](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) returns a **list** of lines, in your case something like `['10']`. So `str(orig_hp)` is a textual representation of this list, like `'[\'10\']'`, which you won't be able to interpret as an integer.

You can just use `f.read()` to read the whole file at once in a string, which will be something like `'10'`, and convert it to a integer:

```
orig_hp = int(f.read())
```

Comment: f.read() was the way to go! Much appreciated. This is working now!